# C++ 2D matrix arithmetic operation using std::transform?

Tags: c++, c++17

I am wondering if it's possible to do 2D matrix multiplication using std::transform? The matrix is stored as 2d vector say:

```
vector<vector<T>>* data.
```

I tried to simply pass a `data.begin()` into the transform function but that won't work. Can someone provide some suggestions or readings? Thanks!

Comment: Is the `*` a typo or are you actually storing the matrix using a *pointer* to a vector of vector of `T`?

Comment: `std::transform` is the wrong shape to do matrix multiplication. It does element-wise unary operations or element-wise binary operations, depending on overload.

Answer (score 2):

### tl;dr: Don't do this, and change your matrix data structure too

You're approaching this the wrong way. `std::transform` is intended as a linear operation, where each element is transformed independently of the others. While it is technically possible to read other matrix elements while iterating over the matrix with an `std::transform`,  it's not a good idea - design-wise and performance wise.

Also, it is better to have the entire matrix' data be contiguous in memory, rather than making n allocations of n separate vectors in different places. Plus, matrix data is sometimes accessed in a column-major rather than row-major way. So - why hold your matrix like that? It's not inherently better to hold all of your data in a simple composition of standard-library data types.

Perhaps you should take the time to see how libraries which actually specialize in matrix multiplications hold their matrices, e.g. [Eigen](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/) or [Intel MKL](https://software.intel.com/en-us/mkl).

Answer (score 1):

Here is some basic code to get you started:

```
    #include <algorithm>
    #include <cctype>
    #include <iostream>
    #include <string>
    #include <vector>

    using namespace std;

    int main()
    {
       vector<vector<int>> data(3);

       data[0] = vector<int>{1, 2, 4};
       data[1] = vector<int>{1, 2, 3};
       data[2] = vector<int>{1, 2, 3};

       vector<vector<int>> data2(3);

       data2[0] = vector<int>{1, 2};
       data2[1] = vector<int>{1, 2};
       data2[2] = vector<int>{1, 2};

       vector<vector<int>> result(3);

       std::transform(data.begin(), data.end(), result.begin(),
       [data2](vector<int> row) -> vector<int> {
           vector<int> ret;
           for (int i = 0; i < data2[0].size(); i++) {
               int rowcolsum = 0;
               for (int k = 0; k < row.size(); k++) {
                   rowcolsum += row[k] * data2[k][i];
               }
               ret.push_back(rowcolsum);
           }
           return ret;
       });

       printf("%d, %d\n", result[0][0], result[0][1]);
       printf("%d, %d\n", result[1][0], result[1][1]);
       printf("%d, %d\n", result[1][0], result[1][1]);
    }
```

Note that this code is ineficient, and is not something I'd recommend you do. However, since you requested a solution utilizing `std::transform`, that is what I provided, despite it's poor usage in this situation. Other answers can direct you to much, much better ways to do matrix multiplication. If you need to work with matrices, I highly recommend using a library dedicated to that function, rather than implement anything yourself.

Comment: You may want to add some more explanation. Code only answers are not very useful.

Comment: Hi, thanks but this one still use for loops which is inefficient?

Comment: @Rockingchief This solution does unnecessary data copies, which makes it inefficient, not the loops.

Comment: It is most definitely inefficient. I was simply trying to use the `std::transform` function as requested, which is not particularly suited for this task

Answer (score 0):

`std::transform` isn't the right algorithm for this. If you really want, you can  `transform` a sequence of indexes (`std::pair<std::size_t, std::size_t>`) rather than the explicit loops I use.

```
using Matrix = std::vector<std::vector<double>>;
using Slice = std::vector<double>; 
// Either a row or a column

Matrix operator*(Matrix lhs, Matrix rhs)
{
    auto rowN = [](const Matrix & mat, std::size_t n) -> Slice
    {
        return mat[n]; 
        // copy of the nth row
    }
    auto colN = [](const Matrix & mat, std::size_t n) -> Slice
    {
        Slice result(mat.size());
        std::transform(mat.begin(), mat.end(), result.begin(), [n](auto & vec){ return vec[n]; });
        // have to copy each row's nth element to get nth column
        return result;
    }

    Matrix result(lhs.size(), { rhs.size(), 0 }); 
    // may be the wrong way round, can't recall. Doesn't matter for square matrices

    for (std::size_t r = 0; r < lhs.size(); r++)
    {
        auto row = rowN(lhs, r);
        for (std::size_t c = 0; c < rhs.size(); c++)
        {
             auto col = colN(rhs, c);
             result[r][c] = std::inner_product(row.begin(), row.end(), col.begin(), 0.);
        }
    }
}
```

I may have done the transpose, but it is simple to swap the rows with the columns from the source matrices. You can also cache the results of `colN`, which trades space for time.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement matrix multiplication succinctly and with 0 unnecessary data copies (unlike other solutions here) with `inner_product`¹ and `transform`:

```
#include <boost/range/numeric.hpp>
#include <boost/range/adaptor/transformed.hpp>

#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

template<class T>
using Matrix = std::vector<std::vector<T>>;

template<class T>
Matrix<T> dot(Matrix<T> const& a, Matrix<T> const& b) {
    using boost::adaptors::transformed;
    auto rows = a.size();
    auto cols = b[0].size();
    Matrix<T> result(rows, std::vector<T>(cols));
    for(decltype(rows) r = 0; r < rows; ++r)
        for(decltype(cols) c = 0; c < cols; ++c)
            result[r][c] = inner_product(a[r], b | transformed([c](auto& row) { return row[c]; }), T{});
    return result;
}
```

Usage:

```
template<class T>
void print_matrix(Matrix<T> const& a) {
    for(auto& r : a) {
        for(auto& c : r)
            std::cout << c << ' ';
        std::cout << '\n';
    }
    std::cout << '\n';
}

int main() {
    Matrix<int> a{
        {1,2,3},
        {4,5,6}
    };
    Matrix<int> b{
        {1,2},
        {3,4},
        {5,6}
    };
    auto r = dot(a, b);

    print_matrix(a);
    print_matrix(b);
    print_matrix(r);

}
```

Outputs:

```
1 2 3 
4 5 6 

1 2 
3 4 
5 6 

22 28 
49 64
```

---

A more efficient storage for matrix is `std::vector<T>(rows * cols)`.

---

¹ Matrix multiplication result cell value is the inner product of the corresponding row and column of the inputs.

If you happen to multiply by one matrix often, it is most efficient to transpose that matrix to avoid walking over rows to extract a column. This also makes the inner product operation easily vectorizable since both inputs become plain arrays (row·row vs row·col).